# How to render a react component on every button click?

Tags: reactjs

Iam creating a react app in which i want to render a component on every button click.But i could do it only once.

```
class AddForm extends React.Component{
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state={
    anotherForm:false,
  }
  this.newForm=this.newForm.bind(this);
}
newForm(){
  this.setState({
    anotherForm:true
  })
}
render(){
return(
  <div>
    <button onClick={this.newForm}>AddForm</button>
    <EducationDetails/>
    {this.state.anotherForm?<EducationDetails/>:null}
  </div>
)
}
}
```

Here the component `EducationDetails` is to be rendered whenever the AddForm button is clicked.But i couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Do you want to add another Form on click or re render the same element ?

Comment: i want to add another form on click that is in the component `EducationDetails`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/abdulex25/mpo2mjwf/)

Lets assume this is your Education Details Component.

```
 class EducationDetails extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
      }

      render() {
        return (<div>
             <p>FirstName: <input type="text" value={this.props.value || ''} /></p>
               <p>LastName:  <input type="text" value={this.props.value || ''} /></p>
              </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

In your AddForm component, You could have a count and whenever you click add more button increment your count and display Education detail form based on your count state.

```
class AddForm extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {value: [], count: 1}; //initial you'll have one form
          }

          addMore(){
            this.setState({count: this.state.count+1})//on click add more forms
          }

          displayForm(){
             let forms = [];
             for(let i = 0; i < this.state.count; i++){
                       forms.push(
                       <div key={i}>
                           <EducationDetails value={this.state.value[i] || ''} />
                       </div>
                    )
             }
             return forms || null;
          }

          render() {
            return (
              <form >
                  {this.displayForm()}        
                  <input type='button' value='add more' onClick={this.addMore.bind(this)}/>
              </form>
            );
          }
        }

        ReactDOM.render(<AddForm />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

You could also remove the form using the same concept  decrement your count something like

```
removeClick(){ 
     this.setState({count: this.state.count - 1}) 
 }
```

And just under your add more button, add another button to remove

```
<input type='button' value='remove' onClick={this.removeClick.bind(this)}/>
```

Comment: is their a way that i can submit all the forms with single button click??Currently i am having submit button for each newly added form.

Comment: @abdul Thank you so much for this answer! I was struggling for quite some time.